# Is chat in comment allowed and should I report them?

Tags: support

I want to report some comment from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53353147/10550549

Maybe @JohnyL missed some knowledge about using regex in C# and @Tan got mad becauseof that.

[image: 1]

They're talking about regex, so I guess I cannot report comments as "not related to the post".

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Most of these comments look like a technical discussion for me, not _chat_.

Comment: The question is **about using regex**. How are the comments not related to the post?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I meant: the last 2 comments. They're not helpful.

Comment: I've purged all comments, as they are no longer pertinent.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question here. The conversation did get a little heated there, flagging them would have been fine, but the whole conversation was no longer needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you give me some tip for the next time I see it? I meant: flagging with what reason?

Comment: 'unfriendly or unkind' on the last comment, 'no longer needed' on any of them, or a custom flag, all would work.

Comment: A disproportional number of arguments like that are caused by a shoddy question.  ideally Tan would have edited the question to avoid getting into this debate.  Done.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, an exchange ("chat") in comments between two or more parties to clarify or point out issues in a post is not only allowed but exactly why the comment feature exist.

It is also clear from exchanges like the one you encountered that commenting should be a privilege that starts at a reasonable reputation level. Otherwise you would find plenty more of these miscommunications.

I don't agree with [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376777/is-chat-in-comment-allowed-and-should-i-report-them/376779#comment647961_376777) on which comment to mark as unfriendly or unkind. The attempt to work out where the misunderstanding is was derailed with the comment starting with:

> I'm telling you once again ...

That one should have been flagged as unfriendly or unkind. Even better would be if users don't let it come that far. It is okay to disagree or have remaining misunderstandings, as long as it is within the borders of civility.

What should have happened that either someone should have suggested to edit the post so future readers would not have to re-raise the same issue. If you want to play the role of peace-keeper you could leave a comment (if you have the privilege) asking if a clarifying edit pointing out the syntax differences would solve the issue at hand.

Once the edit is done, you can can custom flag the post and ask a moderator to nuke all comments as the issue is resolved in an edit. No need to cherry pick.